Possible to show charts in Azure Devops: Wiki based on query result?
I would like to show the results of a query as a chart in Wiki. I know that I can add a chart in the query itself and build a chart in Dashboard based on a query, but this is not what I want.
How can I show a chart instead of manually entering all the details in a mermaid diagram, but like that the mermaid diagram fetches the data itself from the query/query chart?
Thanks!
Google Mermaid diagram connect to query
"Add Query result" in wiki weather able to select chart type

Hi @VSiemon, Welcome to SO. Have you got a chance to check the answer below to use the build-in Query Results in Azure DevOps wiki page? May I know if this is what your need? Hope the information may help resolve your query in this post. Thx for the sharing.

Hi @VSiemon, May I know if the operation below to use the build-in Query Results in Azure DevOps wiki page is what your need? Hope the answer can resolve your query in this post. Have a nice weekend.

Update
As far as I have tested, we are unable to add a diagram (like pie or bar chart) in wiki page to reflect the dynamic results of a query in Azure Boards.
For this, you may create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate Product Group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
As of now, it is also suggested to opt to use the widgets in the Team dashboard for your teams' evaluation.

Instead of showing the query results in a mermaid diagram of project Dashboard, you can opt to add Query Results in a wiki page easily. Here are the steps to insert the results of a query via web UI.

You can collect the queryId from the query URL and use it in markdown syntax.
::: query-table {queryId}
:::


Unfortunately this is not what I am searching for because you can see the query result only as table in the wiki page and not e.g. as pie diagram or bar diagram. So I assume, there is no such possibility yet established by Microsoft?

So you would like to show query results as a pie/bar diagram not a table right?

Hi @VSiemon, I have updated the answer based on your clarification. Hope the information may help.

Hey,  yes, exactly.

I don't think we can add such diagrams in wiki page at the moment. Please check my updated answer to create a suggestion ticket or leverage team dashboard instead. Thx for the sharing.
